# rmarkdown - rticles: Author names not displaying

Tags: r, r-markdown

I have the following code and output for the `rticles::elsevier` article and I cannot get the authors names to appear. The output I get is:

[image: :]

It looks like it might be generating the space for the authors names but no displaying them.

Where the code I used to generate it is:

Code:

```
---
title: Title here
subtitle: Do you have a subtitle? If so, write it here
titlerunning: Short form of title (if too long for head)
authorrunning:
  Short form of author list if too long for running head
thanks: |
  Grants or other notes about the article that should go
  on the front page should be placed here. General
  acknowledgments should be placed at the end of the article.
authors:
  - name: Author 1

keywords:
  - key
  - dictionary
  - word
MSC:
  - MSC code 1
  - MSC code 2 

abstract: |
  Some abstract here

output:
    bookdown::pdf_document2:
      keep_tex: true
      number_sections: no
      toc: no
      tables: true
    base_format: rticles::elsevier_article
header-includes:
  - \usepackage{floatrow}
  - \floatplacement{figure}{H}
  - \usepackage{booktabs}
  - \usepackage{array} 
  - \usepackage{float}

---

# section 1

some writing
```

Even when I use something simple from the following [website](https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown/rticles-usage.html). Where all I changed was - remove the `bibliography: bibliography.bib` line and modify `output: rticles::springer_article` to `output: rticles::elsevier_article`.

Code2:

```
---
title: Title here
subtitle: Do you have a subtitle? If so, write it here
titlerunning: Short form of title (if too long for head)
authorrunning:
  Short form of author list if too long for running head
thanks: |
  Grants or other notes about the article that should go
  on the front page should be placed here. General
  acknowledgments should be placed at the end of the article.
authors:
  - name: Author 1
    address: Department of YYY, University of XXX
    email: abc@def
  - name: Author 2
    address: Department of ZZZ, University of WWW
    email: djf@wef
keywords:
  - key
  - dictionary
  - word
MSC:
  - MSC code 1
  - MSC code 2    
abstract: |
  The text of your abstract.  150 -- 250 words.

output: rticles::elsevier_article

---

# section 1

some writing
```

Answer (score 0):

Your second example displays the authors if you change `authors` to `author`. However the first example still does not work this way..

```
---
title: Title here
subtitle: Do you have a subtitle? If so, write it here
titlerunning: Short form of title (if too long for head)
authorrunning:
  Short form of author list if too long for running head
thanks: |
  Grants or other notes about the article that should go
  on the front page should be placed here. General
  acknowledgments should be placed at the end of the article.
author:
  - name: Author 1
    address: Department of YYY, University of XXX
    email: abc@def
  - name: Author 2
    address: Department of ZZZ, University of WWW
    email: djf@wef
keywords:
  - key
  - dictionary
  - word
MSC:
  - MSC code 1
  - MSC code 2    
abstract: |
  The text of your abstract.  150 -- 250 words.

output: rticles::elsevier_article

---

# section 1

some writing
```